# 2 irreducible polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, irreducible-polynomials

I have to show that the following polynomials are irreducibles in $ \mathbb{Q}[X] $:

> > a) $ f(x) = x^p + (p-1) $
> >
> > b) $\sum_{i=1}^{n}{a_ix^i}$  where $a_i \in \mathbb{Z}$ and there exist a prime $p$ such that $p \nmid a_0$, $p \mid a_i$ for  each $i\ge 1$, and $p^2\nmid a_n$.

so for a) i used that $f(x)$ is irreducible iff $f(x+1)$ is, and then its easy to see that by Eisenstein $f(x+1)$ is irreducible.

I got stuck at b.
i can't find how to change it in order to use Eisenstein (or maybe the solution is without Eisenstein?), can anyone help me please?

Comment: You can use Newton polygon: [link](http://math.ucsd.edu/~kedlaya/18.787/newton-poly.pdf)
Eisenstein and reverse Eisenstein are derivable from it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A polynomial

$$a_nx^n + ... + a_1x + a_0$$

is irreducible if and only if its reversal polynomial

$$a_0x^n + ... + a_{n-1}x + a_n$$

is irreducible.

Now you can use Eisenstein.

Comment: To see that fact above simply insert $\frac{1}{x}$ in the polynomial $a_nx^n + ... + a_1x + a_0$